# How do I get base 64 encoding of a file that use Windows-1251

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a file uploader input, where I accept a file, convert it to base 64 string, and send the payload to a rest api.

However, when I was encoding base64 for utf-8 files, it was working fine. But if I try to get base64 strings of "window-1251" files, it is not converted to a string properly, and the api throws error instead because the base64 string is not valid content.

So my question is how do I get base64 string of a file that uses window-1251 for encoding?

```
var reader2 = new FileReader();
            reader2.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader2.onload = function (e) {
                var sContentStream = e.target.result;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the premise makes no sense. 
*FileReader.readAsDataURL* will always return a valid base64 string from what you gave to it => binary data.

The fact that these bytes represent a text file, with a given encoding is simply ignored by the algorithm.

```js
const rand_data = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(50));
const blob = new Blob([rand_data]);
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e => {
  const dataURL = reader.result
  const base64 = dataURL.slice(dataURL.indexOf(',')+1);
  console.log(base64);
  console.log(atob(base64)); // would throw if invalid data
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

So you are looking at the wrong end of the problem: The consumer may have issues with reading windows-1251 encoded text files, but that's not FileReader's fault.

Now, if you are willing to do the conversion from this encoding to UTF-8 in the browser, then that's still doable, but you's need a way to know which encoding the file you've been given is in.

```js
const win_1251 = new Blob([Uint8Array.from([200])]); // И in windows-1251
// to prove it's not UTF-8
readUTF8Text(win_1251); // �

const reencode_reader = new FileReader();
reencode_reader.onload = e => {
  const utf_8_arr = new TextDecoder('windows-1251')
    .decode(new Uint8Array(reencode_reader.result));
  const utf_8 = new Blob([utf_8_arr], {type: 'text/plain'})
  makeDataURL(utf_8);
  readUTF8Text(utf_8); // И
};
reencode_reader.readAsArrayBuffer(win_1251);

function makeDataURL(blob) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
function readUTF8Text(blob) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(blob);
}
```